# localhost:8000 not accessible using physical IP

Tags: django, localhost, port, lan

I'm trying to access my server on localhost:8000 from my LAN network using my physical IP address: 192.168.1.5:8000 but it's saying 192.168.1.5 refused to connect.

The django server has already

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

And the IP is correct (got it from ipconfig)
My network is set on Private on both computers by the way I can't access that from my own computer too.
I'm not using a VPN

The firewalls are all disabled.
I even allowed the port 8000 using the rule in Inbound rules.
I tried this but didn't work

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="TCP Port 8000" dir=in localport=8000 protocol=TCP action=allow
```

I'm out of ideas, I'm confused. I used to do it before, I'm not a begginer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below command to start your django server on IP.

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.5:8000
```

Comment: Thanks man, I've searched on google for hours, You're are the only one who solved it.
I will accept the answer once they allow me to (4 minutes counter)

Comment: You also need to add the IP in your ALLOWED_HOSTS